# how to resolve changes in Element's id in html?

Tags: python, selenium, odoo

After deployement id of elements are changed. So that can not select those element by id in selenium using python.

Suppose I want to find the below element in HTML.

```html
<input class="o_form_input c_field-65 o_form_field o_form_required" id="o_field_input_22" type="text">
```

I can not use the element's class because there will be elements with the same class.
I would like to find element without using Xpath because if new fields are added in the development side then Xpath will be changed.

Comment: Then you need to find different locators which should remain as it is after deployment.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Which Odoo version do you use? And please take atleast the StackOverflow tour before asking anything.

Comment: You can use other locators like XPath or CssSelector if the id's are changing. Also, if you can provide the HTML source, then we can assist better.

Comment: I believe you can rely on css selectors

Comment: I am using Odoo 10. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score -1):

In that case you should not be locating your element by id (since it not steady).

For example you can use Xpath (other locators may also work):

```
login_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='loginForm']")
```

or

```
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='loginForm']/input[1]")
```

Now the only thing that you can't copy from this, is the xpath it self. That is specific to your website/html/DOM.

An easy way of getting a correct xpath is by inspecting elements using f12 and then right click on the element, go to copy and select [copy xpath]. You can than paste it into your code.

Let me know it this was helpfull!